# Unable to open datasource `' with the following drivers

Tags: django, console, gdal, shapefile, geodjango

I am trying to ensure I have geodjango properly installed so I [can follow this tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#setting-up).

I have used Brew as my installer for Geodjango prequisites: postgresql, postgis, gdal, libgeoip.

My gdal version is most recent: 3.1.2. However when I try to use `ogrinfo world/data/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp` to examine an .shp file it returns this error in the console:

`Unable to open datasource '[this is the name of the file here'] with the following drivers.` It then just lists a whole bunch of drivers.

I can't for the life of me figure out what to do, all the other answers to similar questions recommend upgrading GDAL but mine is the most current version...

Answer (score 7):

Too late for you, but probably useful to others: check your path. Just look at `world/data/`, then look at the structure of your project, then type `ls` on the console and ensure that you're inside the right folder. UPD: Compare - the answer to a similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995291/unable-to-open-shp-file). Good luck))

Comment: I am using the dockerized version and this does not work for me. As I try `docker run osgeo/gdal ogrinfo -al myShapefile.shp` this prints the same error and of course I am 100% sure I am in the right folder. The File is present.

Comment: Yeah, that is a serious red herring error message, if the file isn't found it should fail with a message about that-